# requirejs define a module can not get the return value

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I can not get the exports value  When I import external links
 js file (main.js) as a dependency with requirejs,see the code.

> console.log(m) //undefined

but I define the module "t" as a dependency in internal,it can get the return
value,see the code.

> console.log(n) //test

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/require.js/2.3.3/require.min.js" ></script>

 <script type="text/javascript">
            define("t",["main"],function(m){
             console.log(m) //undefined
             
             return "test";
             
            });
            require(["t"],function(n){
             console.log(n) //test
             
            });
        </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the main.js:

```js
define("m",[],function(){

    return "test";
})
```

So what's the wrong with it?

Comment: Because when you are defining `t`, you're not passing through a variable in place of `m` in the function of the definition.

Comment: How can I pass through a variable when  defining `t`,
if  I change the module 'm' to 'main',it works.Does the module name must be the same with the file name?
`define("main",[],function(){

    return "test";
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your `main.js` module like this and it should work fine:

```
define([],function(){

    return "test";
});
```

Your HTML will be:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>

  <script src="https://cdn.bootcss.com/require.js/2.3.3/require.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    requirejs.config({
      baseUrl: '/', // set proper base path


      paths: {

        "main": "...path to main js...."

      }


    });

    define("t", ["main"], function(m) {
      console.log(m) 

      return "test";

    });

    require(["t"], function(n) {
      console.log(n) //test

    });
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Here is a working [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/BRXoYN?editors=1112)

Comment: Txs,it works. Is there a way to solve without change the main.js?

Comment: @user1841488: It should work just fine if you give your module a name that matches the one in config. ie "main"